# Magento 1.9 How can I hide or exclude in the Navigation Menu category under sub-sub-sub category items

Tags: category, navigation, magento1.9.3, sub-categories

My project running Magento version `Magento1.9.3.2`.I have a menu drop down more category show that main reason hide or remove some item under the category.

This facility Magento admin panel through possible just add '`no`' to Include in Navigation Menu. It's working category, sub category, and sub-sub category. This same facility not hiding or working sub-sub-sub category items.

**Example:** Iphone (Category) - mobiles(Sub Category) - New (Sub-Sub Category ) - iphone 11 pro (Sub-Sub-Sub category) and iphone 11 (Sub-Sub-Sub Category)

How can I hide iphone 11 pro only navigation bar ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `catalog.xml` on following path :  `app/design/default/THEMENAME/layout/catalog.xml` with this XML definition to remove the category filters from the left-layered navigation in Magento.

Follow this :

```
<reference name="catalog.leftnav">
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
```

I hope it helps..